# Nodebb web app has failed to start and just crashes

Tags: mongodb, nodebb

I managed to install the nodebb forum very well and i was able to use it... On the next day , it failed to start and just crashes. I think my problem was that connect mongo cannot easily connect to mongodb database. probably help me look at this error.

```
    16/2 20:26 [4171] - info: Launching web installer on port 4567

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
 Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)
    at listen (net.js:1065:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1139:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/home/goldsoft25/Desktop/NodeJS/NodeBB-master/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
    at launchExpress (/home/goldsoft25/Desktop/NodeJS/NodeBB-master/install/web.js:53:15)
```

Comment: are you using a windows or mac?

Comment: No... i am using linux mint.... ... It happened after installing some push notification server called countly server.. I think it creates another instance of mongdb database process. Thanx for your time

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error for any of application running on top of node. Both applications are pointing to same port, 4567 in your case .
You will have to change the port of one application or kill application when swapping between each app.

Comment: Thank you for your effort... I changed the port and it started working... but then it then stopped working ... so I restorted using the ./nodebb log which works perfectly even though the other nodejs applications are running